# Login Facebook in webView with SDK [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app in which I have login via facebook SDK.

I think that when I logged in and webView load the https://www.facebook.com

and automatically login own facebook but it doesn't work

Still have to input Account and Password [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0XvM.png)

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    else if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
    {
        print("Successfully logged in with facebook...")
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://www.facebook.com")!))
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Facebook SDK` itself handles all process of loading the `www.facebook.com` and `login` process. You no need to implement the `UIWebView` and all. After login the delegate method `didCompleteWith result:....` will call. You only need to check the status of your login process by follows,

If you already `logged in` with Facebook in safari, then logged account will get authenticate by Facebook, otherwise you first need to enter you facebook id and password, then only you will get authenticate by Facebook.

```
 func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if (result!.isCancelled) {// If user cancelled the facebook login
        // Do stuffs after Your user cancelled login process
    } else if ((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {// If user successfully loggedin to the Facebook
        // Do stuffs after Your user successfully logged in.
    } else if error != nil {// Any error occurs
        // Error while trying to login 
    }
}
```

You can refer my `GitHub project` called `SocialLogin` for social logins (Twitter, google, linkedin) [here](https://github.com/karthironald/SocialLogin-iOS/tree/google_signin/SocialLogin)

Thanks:)

Comment: thanks, Karthick. But I have a facebook app web, I need a webView to load it. Or I did not understand what you mean?

Comment: Don't you want to use the Facebook app?

Comment: I described my answer for webView only... not using facebook app.